# Can you use "nothing more, nothing less than" when speaking of a person?

Tags: phrase-usage

Example:

> A ugly rumor about him circulated in the city. The person who started
>   it was **nothing more, nothing less** than his wife.

Can I use the phrase in this way? If not, what's a more adequate option?

Comment: "[none other than](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/none_other_than)", probably. But it would be good if you describe your intended meaning. Do you wish to express the feeling of surprise? Is your native language Russian, and if yes, is the original phrase "[не кто иной, как](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=%ED%E5+%EA%F2%EE+%E8%ED%EE%E9%2C+%EA%E0%EA)"?

Comment: @CowperKettle Yes, but I think your suggestion is perfect. Wanna to write an answer instead?

Comment: Or "no one else than" or  "nobody else than".

Comment: By the way, "wanna to write" is incorrect. The correct phrase is "want to write". Unless you are trying to emulate speech, then you can write "wanna write", without the "to", but only in an informal situation.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'An ugly' .. not 'A ugly'. ??

Comment: or "...no less than his wife."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the phrase "nothing more, nothing less" in relation to a person, just not as you have. As @CowperKettle has said, the phrase you are looking for is "none other than" (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**none other than**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/none_other_than)
>   *Phrase*
>   Used to emphasize the surprising identity of a person or thing:
>   *"her first customer was none other than Henry du Pont"*

You might use "nothing more, nothing less" in relation to a person who thinks they are of higher status than they actually are, or a person who tries to act outside their remit or area of responsibility. For example:

> He [spoke back](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/talk_back) to the Sergeant. He had to remember he was a private:
>   nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the phrase you are looking for is **[none other than](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/none_other_than)**.